# Printing no output while fetching data from mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, express, model

My database is :

> db.userTable.find()
>   { "_id" : ObjectId("5e25fc1520d6388df2bd7560"), "username" : "Alex", "password" : "12Ajkh" }
>   { "_id" : ObjectId("5e25fc2820d6388df2bd7561"), "username" : "Sam", "password" : "156jkh" }

My index.js is :

```
    let User = require('./models/user_model');
    app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
      User.find({},(err,user)=>{      
        if(err)       
          throw err;       
        console.log(">>>>>",user); 
        });     
     });
```

This is my ./model/user_model.js

```
let mongoose=require('mongoose');

let userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    username:
    {
        type: String,
        required:true
    },

    password:
    {
        type:String,
        required:true
    }
});

let User = module.exports=mongoose.model("User",userSchema);
```

This is giving me no output in console!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you're using `+`, that's why it's not give you output in your `console`. Please remove `+` in your `console.log` and change it to `,`.

️‍♂️ You can see the code below:

```
let User = require('./models/user_model');
app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
  User.find({},(err,user)=>{      
    if(err)       
      throw err;       
    console.log(">>>>>", user); 
    });     
});
```

**Updated: ./model/user_model.js**

make sure your `collection` name it's same with the your collection in MongoDB.

From your `database`, you're using `userTable`, not `user`. So, in your model, change it to `userTable` collection, not only `user`.

That's why, in your collection from `command line`, you get data, but in your `code` you get an empty array.

️‍♂️ Now, **you can use this code below** in your model: `./model/user_model.js`

```js
let mongoose=require('mongoose');

let userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    username:
    {
        type: String,
        required:true
    },

    password:
    {
        type:String,
        required:true
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("userTable",userSchema, 'userTable');
```

**Info:** Change `user` to `userTable` collection.

Now, you can see the output in your `console`.

I hope, it's can help you.

Comment: I made the changes but it is still showing me empty array